# Properly decrypting a file using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding - BadPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption

When I try to decrypt the following file, I get this `BadPaddingException` at the following line. I believe the file is encrypted properly.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:810)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:675)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1970)
    **at MyProgram.decryptFile(MyProgram.java:1437)**
    at MyProgram.decrypt(MyProgram.java:865)
    at MyProgram.access$900(MyProgram.java:68)
    at MyProgram$1.messagesAdded(MyProgram.java:353)
    at javax.mail.event.MessageCountEvent.dispatch(MessageCountEvent.java:150)
    at javax.mail.EventQueue.run(EventQueue.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is the decryption code, I can send code on the encrypted part as well:

```
private static void decryptFile(String file, String password, byte[] Salt, byte[] IV, String attachmentunecryptedhash, String attachmentoriginalsizeString, String attachmentcreated)
{
        long attachmentSize = 0;
        String attachmentCreated = null;
        String attachmentModified = null;
        String attachmentHash = null;
        byte[] buffers = new byte[16];
        byte[] endOfFile = new byte[16];
        int counterForFile = 0;
        int attachmentoriginalsize = 0;
        int noBytes = 0;

        try
        {
            if(Paths.get(file.trim()).toFile().exists() == true) //If the File Exists
            {
                //Creates Secret Key For Decryption -- Passes Password, Salt, Iterations, and Key Length
                PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), Salt, 65536, 256);
                SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
                SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
                SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

                //Initalizes Cipher For Decrypt Mode -- Passes Password and Salt
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(IV));

                //Prepares To Write New Buffer Containing Decrypted Information to Output File
                String unencryptedFile = file.trim().replaceAll(".aes", "");
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.trim());
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(unencryptedFile);
                attachmentoriginalsize = Integer.parseInt(attachmentoriginalsizeString);



                //Writes Encrypted File to Disk Using Secure Cipher Output Stream
                while((noBytes = fileInputStream.read(buffers)) != -1)
                {

                    //Writes 1 encrypted byte at a time
                    fileOutputStream.write(cipher.update(buffers,0,noBytes));
                    //counterForFile += 16;
                }

                buffers = cipher.doFinal();  //Line 1437 Where the Error Exists

                fileOutputStream.write(buffers);
                fileOutputStream.flush();


                //Close Files, Cleanup
                fileInputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream.close();

                System.exit(1);

}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that it was encrypted properly?

Comment: FYI, your variable `attachmentunecryptedhash` implies that your method of integrity verification is a hash computed over the plaintext.  In order for your encryption to be CPA-secure, you should use a cryptographic MAC computed over the ciphertext, which must then be verified before decryption takes place.  See this thread for more information:  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac

Comment: I don't directly see any error, we would need the encryption code and - if possible - some test data as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that can cause a "Bad Padding" error.  Basically anything that causes the end of the last block not to match the expected padding will throw the error.  Possible causes include: incorrect padding setting, incorrect key, corrupted cyphertext and others.

To try and diagnose the problem, set the decryption side to `NoPadding`.  This will accept anything, and allow you to examine the output:

- complete garbage: you probably have an error in the key or different mode settings.
- first block garbage: you may have a key error or an IV error.
- last block garbage: likely a corrupt end to the cyphertext file.
- a correct decryption with some strange bytes at the end: the strange bytes are the padding.

If it really is just the padding, then set the decryption function to expect that sort of padding.  Otherwise check that the key/IV/cyphertext is **byte-for-byte** the same for both encryption and decryption.

It is *vital* that you set a padding mode after diagnosis.  `NoPadding` is insecure.